# Ajax request returning 404

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an Ajax request that's returning a 404. Here is the JavaScript:

```
function rowClicked(id) {
    console.log(id);
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Details.aspx/GetComment",
            data: { "id": id },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
    });
}
```

And here is the C# method in Details.aspx.cs - the code behind Details.aspx

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string GetComment(int id)
{
    return "Test";
}
```

Could anyone offer any insight as to why I might be getting a 404 response?

Comment: Which means, the page is not found. Your url path might be wrong

Comment: I'm pretty certain it's not wrong, my GetComment method is in the Details.aspx.cs code behind.

Comment: I'm saying that your path to `Details.aspx` is wrong. Try removing the parameter from the method and try. But I'm not sure since I'm not a .NET expert

Comment: The path is definitely wrong - that's what the error means.  If you go to the page where the script is executed and change the URL so that the filename is `Details.aspx`, you'll see it too gives a 404 error.  If `details.aspx` is in the root folder, change the url in the script to `/details.aspx` (prefix with a `/`)

Comment: Chrome's console gives the link it's trying to reach and it matches up. Not saying what I have is right as it's obviously not but I cant work out why it appears to be trying to access the right thing?

Comment: maybe this is what you need: url: "/Details.aspx/GetComment",
anyway check the url in the request, try it by yourself in the browser and you'll see. it might be that youre accepting GET request only as well, not post

Comment: and the same chrome console does return 404 for the request? :P

Comment: @mikus this is what it shows: POST http://localhost:50156/vLocationHistory/Details.aspx/GetComment 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Try changing your data line to data: JSON.stringify({"id": id})

Comment: @MikeHe still getting 404

Comment: so its not found, clearly :P change it to GET see if same happens, if so, try to check your configuration

Comment: also the data type might be not correct, isnt your method returning xml or sth? :P

Comment: @mikus I've changed it to get and it's still trying to retrieve the same (as far as I'm aware, correct) link. It's also passing the id correctly.

Comment: @mikus my method is returning a string which is what I want. Even if the JavaScript didn't get the datatype it's expecting using console.log will output what it did receive.

Comment: Is this webforms or MVC? If webforms, you have to access the data with result.d. Try logging that. I usually add a error handler after the success. Try adding this as well error: function(a,b,c){ console.log(a.responseText);}

Comment: @MikeHe It's webforms not MVC. I've tried adding the error code and responseText is a very large formatted response but long story short it says 404 not found.

Comment: I would remove the parameter to the method in the code-behind. Change your type to 'POST' if it isn't already, and change data to "{}". (include quotation marks). If you set a breakpoint on your method, does it get hit?

Comment: @MikeHe it's still not being hit. I'm going to ask a colleague that previously worked on this site to see if he knows of anything that could cause this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: clearly the method ios not available, you might have some configuration in webconfig that prevents that, or its just not available under this port/path

Answer (score 0):

As most of the people stated, your url might be wrong. 
Try to use it like this , maybe it will solve the issue :

```
<%=ResolveUrl("~/Details.aspx/GetComment") %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The page isn't in the root so I tried this without ~/ and I'm still getting 404. Thanks though.

Comment: What I mean is what is folder structure to that aspx file.

Comment: It was in the same folder, I've got around it now doing it a different way.

Comment: so, whats the problem after all?